# Combining Node.js/Socket.io & Wordpress/PHP: PHP emitter?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, redis, socket.io

I have a site already built in wordpress. (If I were to do it all over, I'd probably use more of a MEAN approach...) Nevertheless, I am at a point where I need to pass data specific to a logged in user to my Node.js app.

To avoid possible client-side manipulation (I have very mischievous users) I was wondering if the following is possible:

Currently they are "submitting" a new post of a custom post type via WP-REST-API. (Nonces handled, etc etc...)

This post has specific `post_meta` data that needs to be processed in the node app.
Initially, with WP REST API That post goes in as a `status: 'draft'`. 
Simultaneously in the PHP, use a PHP emitter like [Socket.io-php-emitter](https://github.com/ashiina/socket.io-php-emitter) to send specific user and post meta data to the Node app (which is retrieved safely using the wp functions like `get_the_id()` and `get_post_meta()` and `get_user_meta()`)

On success of the data processing to this point, use `socket.emit` in the already enqeued js file to send an "ok" event -- Triggering the Node app to process the data from the PHP emitter and return it's responses back to the client.

Upon receiving the result, update the post status to either publish or delete based on success of the app.

I am asking here before diving in because I realize mixing these technologies is a bit unpopular, but it's the route I am on for now. To me, this theoretically should work. Has anyone had experience with a PHP emitter?